# Using the OrbitControl causes whole scene to disappear in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I use the original editor example in which ships with the **R69 version of Three.js**. I add OrbitControls to the Viewport.js file with the following code (declaration of orbit controls and integration into scene with render routine) then scene starts to rotate with constant speed but if I interact in any way with scene adding object/s, mouse clicking, **click+drag the whole scene disappears**.

```
var camera = editor.camera;
camera.position.fromArray( editor.config.getKey( 'camera/position' ) );
//camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3().fromArray( editor.config.getKey( 'camera/target' ) ) );    

// ANIMATION ORBIT CONTROLS     
var orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
orbitControls.autoRotate = true;
var clock = new THREE.Clock();  
//


function render() {
    sceneHelpers.updateMatrixWorld();
    scene.updateMatrixWorld();

    // ADDITIONAL CODE 
    var delta = clock.getDelta();
    orbitControls.update(delta/10);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    // ADDITIONAL CODE END 

    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

    if ( renderer instanceof THREE.RaytracingRenderer === false ) {
        renderer.render( sceneHelpers, camera );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put a jsfiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not support for the OrbitControls (`var orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);`) for the Three.js (R54) version of JsFiddle so its hard to reporoduce it.

Comment: Trying to add OrbitControls at the editor example in the THREE.JS causes the malfunctioning. But if I start the plain project from scratch adding the OrbitConstrols then everything works fine, I believe that it is obvious that editor example uses its own method of initialization for controls and which is conflicting with any attempt of adding additional control. I looked in editor folder to find that specific code for Control initialization, but I couldn't